# UI Automation example error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _CLSID_AccPropServices

Tags: c++, winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to edit dialog control properties so the UI is fully accessible for screen readers. I have tried the following code sample (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/Win32/Control_Name)

```
// At the top of the C++ file.
#include <initguid.h> 
#include "objbase.h"
#include "uiautomation.h" 
IAccPropServices* _pAccPropServices = NULL;


// Run when the UI is created.
void SetControlAccessibleName(HWND hDlg)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_AccPropServices,
        nullptr,
        CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&_pAccPropServices));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Load up the localized accessible name for the control.
        WCHAR szName[MAX_LOADSTRING];
        LoadString(
            hInst,
            IDS_COMBOBOX_BIRDS,
            szName,
            ARRAYSIZE(szName));

        // Now set the name on the control. This gets exposed through UIA 
        // as the element's Name property.
        hr = _pAccPropServices->SetHwndPropStr(
            GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_COMBOBOX_BIRDS),
            OBJID_CLIENT,
            CHILDID_SELF,
            Name_Property_GUID,
            szName);
    }
}


// Run when the UI is destroyed.
void ClearControlAccessibleName(HWND hDlg)
{
    if (_pAccPropServices != nullptr)
    {
        // Clear the custom accessible name set earlier on the control.
        MSAAPROPID props[] = { Name_Property_GUID };
            
        _pAccPropServices->ClearHwndProps(
            GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_COMBOBOX_BIRDS),
            OBJID_CLIENT,
            CHILDID_SELF,
            props,
            ARRAYSIZE(props));

        _pAccPropServices->Release();
        _pAccPropServices = NULL;
    }
}
```

when trying to build the solution, the following error shows up:

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _CLSID_AccPropServices

I've tried the following things:

- I have tried adding oleacc.lib to the Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependecies.
  I checked with ProcessMonitor if the oleacc.lib was found succesfully, which it was.
- Adding aleacc.h like so:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include "objbase.h"
#include "uiautomation.h"
```

- I tried changing the CLSID_AccPropServices to a different GUID defined in the same library. So I used IID_IAccPropServices to test if it would build. And it did.

Comment: use `__uuidof(CAccPropServices)` in place `CLSID_AccPropServices`

Comment: I don't reproduce with your code as is, Visual Studio 2019, it works fine as long as you include initguid.h

Comment: @SimonMourier - *initguid.h* here can not help, because exist only `EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CAccPropServices;` and all. nothing more. need use *uuid.lib* (here this symbol defined) or (better) use `__uuidof(CAccPropServices)`. visual tudio here unrelated at all

Comment: @RbMm - don't know how you're testing, but if I take the code and remove initguid, it doesn't compile and gives this error. I also know Windows programming a bit you know.

Comment: @SimonMourier - i dont test at all, but go from general - how is `CLSID_CAccPropServices` defined ? i search in sdk headers and only in *oleacc.h* found *EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CAccPropServices;* - how you can view - here no any actual definition (value) and *initguid* can not help in such case.

Comment: @RbMm - I always test when I affirm something. Take that https://pastebin.com/raw/mVF8CheF put it in a new Visual Studio 2019 C++ console app, Windows SDK 10 and it won't compile. Uncomment initguid and it will. Note I'm not interested to know why, I know about __uuidof etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier - and what was compile error (not linker error ?) version of visual studio not play any role. *I'm not interested to know why* - i always interesting in this. i simply try explain that in that case *initguid* can not affect this error. definition of *CLSID_CAccPropServices* **not is header files** but in *uuid.lib*

Comment: @RbMm - Like I said, the error is the same as in the question: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_AccPropServices if you don't put initguid.

Comment: @SimonMourier - i confused by you say *won't *compile**. about *LNK2001* - i have very deep understand in this - in what **source** of this error. definition of *_CLSID_AccPropServices* in *uuid.lib* (x86)- (you can search this symbols by self in lib files). and **no definition** of this in any header files. task not in **initguid.h** but in **uuid.lib**

Comment: @SimonMourier *initguid.h* play role when symbol defined with *DEFINE_GUID* macro. but here we have another case - no such macro, but only *EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CAccPropServices;* and all. can i ask - which guid *value* in this case must have `CLSID_CAccPropServices` ? where is this defined ? no definition in any headers from sdk. but exist definition in *uuid.lib*

Comment: @RbMm - not sure what you're asking here: if you include initguid then obviously DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_AccPropServices...) in oleacc.h (line 179 for me) will suffice to define the guid completely so it will work https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/shared/guiddef.h#L61

Comment: @SimonMourier - so task in that - we have **different** *oleacc.h* files. in my version - not exist `DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_AccPropServices...) ` but exist `EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CAccPropServices`

Comment: looking for different sdk version from microsoft, begin from 7.1 - everywhere i view only `EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CAccPropServices;` so i assume that you use not ms sdk

Comment: @RbMm - haaaaa... you're using CLSID_CAccPropServices... I'm talking CLSID_AccPropServices here, just like in the question.

Comment: @SimonMourier - yes, really my mistake. i use *CLSID_**C**AccPropServices* which is near *class DECLSPEC_UUID("b5f8350b-0548-48b1-a6ee-88bd00b4a5e7")
CAccPropServices;* but you *CLSID_AccPropServices* . and *CLSID_**C**AccPropServices*  exist in *uuid.lib* so simply not note additional **C** symbols

Comment: @RbMm - well, the original fault is also Microsoft's one :-) BTW we can check they are the same https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=b5f8350b-0548-48b1-a6ee-88bd00b4a5e7

Comment: @SimonMourier of course the same. and also exist symbol `CLSID_CAccPropServices` in *uuid.lib* - you can found it even with notepad. sorry, i not note at begin difference in name